# Laravel: Pluralization and irregular words for model names

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am just starting with Laravel, and I have a question on how to solve this "the right way".

I have lots of words in spanish that the plural is not simply appending an "s" in the end, for example, the plural for "Especialidad" is "Especialidades", or the plural for "ObraSocial" is "ObrasSociales".

I'm seeing that there is src/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php with an $irregular array. Is the correct way to add that words in this array (I don't think so..), or is there any other place from where I can put all the words that I need to use?

thanks!

Comment: It is common practice to develop software using english names for classes and variables. As a result magic functionality like pluralization is going to be based on english... You can either try and hack it, like your own suggestion above, and see if you can cover all the bases... or you just program in english...

Comment: @Populus, the pluralizer can also be used for output.

Comment: @Populus, my bad, I hadn't paid much attention to the title of the question. In that case, yes, I also recommend writing programming in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **right** way to do it would probably be to make a new class, extending `Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer` called something like `SpanishPluralizer` and override all `$plural`, `$singular`, `$irregular` and `$uncountable` properties to Spanish equivalents.

If you'll be pluralizing only a few strings though, it would be okeish to simply override the `$irregular` property.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be going this route for the time being, making a new class.